# Style of Publications chapter of PhD thesis

Tags: thesis

I am writing my PhD thesis currently, and I am wondering about examples of the style for the list of publications (by myself).

I should mention, that my thesis is the classical type meaning a monogram, not just my publications stapled together with some filling, which has become common in some places. I expect around 150 pages in all (field is physics, for reference).

The work that has been published is already included in the thesis in one chapter per publication (plus other chapters of course, for methodology, introduction etc).
The list of publications would be an appendix.

I am using the Arsclassica style, and doing it similarly to the Publications chapter used in ClassicThesis, see [page 9 in the ClassicThesis pdf](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/ClassicThesis.pdf).

It looks nice, but I also heard that some people also include the front page of each publication as a figure or similar. Does anyone have examples of that, or ways to implement it nicely?

**From the answers/comments** I can conclude, and totally agree, that since it's so flexible, it probably doesn't matter much. I was just looking for different options/inspiration.

Comment: I do not see why one should do that. As for papers are typical  few journal pages in length I would rather places them as an appendix.

Comment: Ask your supervisor.

Comment: I have already asked my supervisor, but the specific rules seem to be quite flexible.
The simplest by far is to simply make a `\refsection` with my own publications, I was just wondering if others had done it differently.
Some of the papers are more than 10-15 pages so therefore seem to be too large to completely include.

Comment: Check the requirement of your university. If they are flexible, you probably want to ask the publishing people, not academic people..

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to specify what exactly you are aiming at with this chapter? Is your thesis a cumulative one and this is just a list of what has been included or does it even suffice just to list them? Or is your thesis a monograph and the publications in question already contain part of your results? Or is this as CV-like section that is demanded by the exam guideline? “I was just wondering if others had done it differently” is not a good question for this format as any answer is equally valid.

Answer (score 2):

If the guidelines are flexible and your advisor has not provided you with specific guidance, then I think you can conclude that it really does not matter.  Including a list of your own publications is not a universal requirement for a thesis anyway.  Look at some past theses from students in your program, and  do something similar.

The reality would seem to be that it doesn't much matter how you format things.  If the thesis examiners want to look up your original publications, any format that makes them clear should be fine.  I have never had trouble looking at a student's original research papers, with or without a dedicated section listing them.